# Twilio carrier info error code 61003 with Australian number

Tags: twilio

we recently started using Twilio lookup with the Carrier Info add-on to validate phone number format and determine the number type (mobile/landline). Most of our numbers have been U.S. or UK and we haven't had a problem.

Today we encountered our first Australian number and it caused an error for the Carrier Info portion of the response, specifically code 61003, "Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met." The basic lookup portion of the response, with country code, number format, etc., is fine.

However, when I try the same number on the public-facing Twilio web page (https://www.twilio.com/lookup) the whole lookup including carrier info works fine.

Does anyone know if there are different API call requirements for numbers in different countries? Or what else might be wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this, including your Account Sid and the number you got this result for. It's certainly weird that it would work on the product page but not via the API.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that this was a temporary error at Twilio. After the weekend, and without any changes in my code, the same number worked fine. Twilio support said they weren't aware of any problems with the service but that they would alert the engineering team that this had happened.